# re-create a GCC C project only as preprocessor files?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, preprocessor

i have a large project using make files and more but i want to recreate the same project will all folder hierarchy with just the code after the preprocessing was done (including macro expending)

i couldn't find how to do it in a large project just on a single files.

does anyone know a tool or a command that can re-create a GCC c project back to a preprocessor mode ?

Comment: You can use `gcc -E` to create the source file after preprocessing.  This is useful for debugging, but I wouldn't recommend saving the output and making it the project.

Comment: gcc -E requires to also have in the command line the output file. in a large project that already exist with a Makefile this is not applicable.